# How can I use a link to navigate between input tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

How can i use the next Tab herf to navigate between tabs or using any other button?

here html and jquery

http://embed.plnkr.co/wSRKmDw7L2J5tdYc4Hwj

Comment: Care to post your code please :)

Answer (score 2):

Attach an event handler that simulates a click on the tab:

```
$("a.nexttab").click(function() {
    $("a[data-content=tab-two]").click();
});
```

Comment: thank you very much Streetlamp.. working 100%